# What is Metric Refreshing with regard to HBase monitoring?

Tags: java, hbase, jconsole

I am trying to enable JMX for monitoring HBase via jconsole. The document says that one needs to enable Metric Refreshing.

Any idea why?

This is the [link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/hbase/hbase-0.20.1/docs/metrics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metric refreshing means, updating latest values for metrics. You will configure refresh interval for those contexts in properties file.